# Insert value to Database base on Month?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, sql-update

I can't insert value into month. I have 12 column for each month. My code only store the value in January. Is it ok if i use switch?

```
if ($_GET['do'] == 'insert')
    {   
        $p_aid          = $_GET['id'];
        $t_no           = $_POST['t_no'];       
        $t_month        = $_POST['t_month']; //dropdown
        $t_value        = $_POST['t_value']; //value based on month selected
        $t_year         = $_POST['t_year']; 


        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_detail (p_aid,t_not_year) ";
        $sql .= "VALUES ($p_aid,'$t_no''$t_year')";
        mysql_query($sql);

        switch ($t_month) {

        case $t_month = "Jan";
            $sql = "UPDATE tbl_detail SET t_jan = '$t_value'";      
            $sql .= "WHERE p_aid = $p_aid AND t_no = $t_no";
        break;

        case $t_month = "Feb";
            $sql = "UPDATE tbl_detail SET t_feb = '$t_value'";      
            $sql .= "WHERE p_aid = $p_aid AND t_no = $t_no";
        break;

            mysql_query($sql);
        }

        redirect("basicview.php?id=$p_aid&type=success&msg=new+row+added");
    }
```

Comment: your  `mysql_query($sql);` is inside switch `block` put it out

Comment: why are you updating table ? you can directly insert the month in the query at first time.

Comment: why do you have 12 different columns and only ever use one of them? You certainly could do something easier but a case statement is safer than injecting the month name into the insert string.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Totally agree.  I updated my post to use an array accessed twice to sanitize which hold so long as the server doesn't require the var to be set.

Answer (score 3):

Well, first, your case statements are not correct.

```
case $t_month = "Jan";
```

should be

```
case "Jan":
```

or

```
case 0:
```

(whatever the values of `$t_month` can be).

If the dropdown has the text you want as the value, then a `switch` isn't necessary.

If it has the number of the month, then an array would work, too without as many evaluations.

EDIT: This is in addition to Tome's comment.
EDIT #2: If the dropdown *does* have the text, then you **most definitely** want to check that it is valid so that you don't add more SQL injection options.

And, continuing to edit... Something like this will address a lot of the issues:

```
if ($_GET['do'] == 'insert')
{   
    $p_aid          = (int)$_GET['id'];
    $t_no           = (int)$_POST['t_no'];

    $months = array(''=>'Jan', 'Jan'=>'Jan', 'Feb'=>'Feb', 'Mar'=>'Mar', 'Apr'=>'Apr', 'Mar'=>'Mar', 'Apr'=>'Apr', 'May'=>'May', 'Jun'=>'Jun', 'Jul'=>'Jul', 'Aug'=>'Aug', 'Sep'=>'Sep', 'Oct'=>'Oct', 'Nov'=>'Nov', 'Dec'=>'Dec');

    $t_month        = $months[$months[$_POST['t_month']]]; //dropdown
    $t_value        = $_POST['t_value']; //value based on month selected
    $t_year         = (int)$_POST['t_year']; 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_detail (p_aid,t_not_year,t_" . strtolower($t_month) . ") ";
    $sql .= "VALUES ($p_aid,'$t_no''$t_year', '" . $t_month . "')";
    mysql_query($sql);

    redirect("basicview.php?id=$p_aid&type=success&msg=new+row+added");
}
```

Though, I am not sure what you are trying to do with `'$t_no''$t_year'`, but I'm betting that isn't right.

Comment: and the logical operator `==`

Comment: @TomeӾsanS Did I miss that in the update (was writing while you commented).

Comment: @JeremyMiller thanks man. It works. I'm really new to PHP. I even don't know how to write an array. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you have no need to use switch case. use the following code to store related month and their values. try this....

```
if ($_GET['do'] == 'insert')
{   
    $p_aid          = $_GET['id'];
    $t_no           = $_POST['t_no'];       
    $t_month        = $_POST['t_month']; //dropdown
    $t_value        = $_POST['t_value']; //value based on month selected
    $t_year         = $_POST['t_year']; 


    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_detail (p_aid,t_no, t_year, $t_month) ";
    $sql .= "VALUES ($p_aid,'$t_no','$t_year','$t_value')";
    mysql_query($sql);

}
```

Comment: if you got the same column name in $t_month then you use this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
if ($_GET['do'] == 'insert')
    {   
        $p_aid          = $_GET['id'];
        $t_no           = $_POST['t_no'];       
        $t_month        = $_POST['t_month']; //dropdown
        $t_value        = $_POST['t_value']; //value based on month selected
        $t_year         = $_POST['t_year']; 


        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_detail (p_aid,t_not_year) ";
        $sql .= "VALUES ($p_aid,'$t_no''$t_year')";
        mysql_query($sql);

        $col="t_".strtolower($t_month);
        $sql = "UPDATE tbl_detail SET $col = '$t_value'";      
        $sql .= "WHERE p_aid = $p_aid AND t_no = $t_no";
        mysql_query($sql);

        redirect("basicview.php?id=$p_aid&type=success&msg=new+row+added");
    }
```